# Why is it appending the values to all of the players and not one at a time?

Tags: python-3.x

In a program that I am creating for the card game 'war', I am having trouble with dealing cards to each player.
The code looks like...

```
import random

count = True


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, hand):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = hand


players = []
hand = []

deck = ['Ace of Diamonds', '2 of Diamonds', '3 of Diamonds', '4 of Diamonds', '5 of Diamonds',
        '6 of Diamonds', '7 of Diamonds', '8 of Diamonds', '9 of Diamonds', '10 of Diamonds', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'King of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', '2 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts', '4 of Hearts', '5 of Hearts', '6 of Hearts', '7 of Hearts',
        '8 of Hearts', '9 of Hearts', '10 of Hearts', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Queen of Hearts', 'King of Hearts', 'Ace of Spades', '2 of Spades', '3 of Spades', '4 of Spades', '5 of Spades', '6 of Spades', '7 of Spades',
        '8 of Spades', '9 of Spades', '10 of Spades', 'Jack of Spades', 'Queen of Spades', 'King of Spades', 'Ace of Clubs', '2 of Clubs', '3 of Clubs', '4 of Clubs', '5 of Clubs', '6 of Clubs', '7 of Clubs',
        '8 of Clubs', '9 of Clubs', '10 of Clubs', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Queen of Clubs', 'King of Clubs']
random.shuffle(deck)

while count == True:
    try:
        print()
        player_count = int(input("Number of players: "))
        if player_count == 0:
            player_count = int('a')
        count = False

    except ValueError:
        print("Oops, we counldn't understand that.")
        print()


for i in range(1, player_count + 1):
    name = input(f"Player {i}'s name: ")
    card_count = 52 / player_count
    while card_count > 0:
        card = deck[0]
        deck.remove(card)
        hand.append(card)
        card_count -= 1
    players.append(Player(name, hand))

print()
for p in players:
    print(f'{p.name} :  {p.hand}')
    print()
```

If I enter 2 players named jo and bob, the out put looks like...

```
Number of players: 2
Player 1's name: jo
Player 2's name: bob

jo :  ['8 of Hearts', '6 of Clubs', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'Queen of Spades', 'King of Spades', 'King of Diamonds', '8 of Clubs', '5 of Hearts', '8 of Diamonds', 'Jack of Clubs', '10 of Hearts', '5 of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts', '6 of Diamonds', '10 of Clubs', '7 of Diamonds', '4 of Spades', 'King of Hearts', '2 of Clubs', 'Queen of Clubs', '3 of Clubs', '6 of Hearts', '2 
of Hearts', '4 of Diamonds', '5 of Spades', 'Ace of Spades', 'Queen of Hearts', '9 of Diamonds', 'Ace of Diamonds', '3 of Diamonds', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Ace of Clubs', '9 of Clubs', '8 of Spades', '2 of Spades', '6 of Spades', '3 of Spades', '10 of Spades', '7 of Spades', '9 of Spades', '4 of Clubs', '9 of Hearts', '5 of Clubs', '3 of Hearts', '2 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '7 of Clubs', '10 of Diamonds', 'Jack of Diamonds']

bob :  ['8 of Hearts', '6 of Clubs', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'Queen of Spades', 'King of Spades', 'King of Diamonds', '8 of Clubs', '5 of Hearts', '8 of Diamonds', 'Jack of 
Clubs', '10 of Hearts', '5 of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts', '6 of Diamonds', '10 of Clubs', '7 of Diamonds', '4 of Spades', 'King of Hearts', '2 of Clubs', 'Queen of Clubs', '3 of Clubs', '6 of Hearts', '2 of Hearts', '4 of Diamonds', '5 of Spades', 'Ace of Spades', 'Queen of Hearts', '9 of Diamonds', 'Ace of Diamonds', '3 of Diamonds', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Ace of Clubs', '9 of Clubs', '8 of Spades', '2 of Spades', '6 of Spades', '3 of Spades', '10 of Spades', '7 of Spades', '9 of Spades', '4 of Clubs', '9 of Hearts', '5 of Clubs', '3 of Hearts', '2 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '7 
of Clubs', '10 of Diamonds', 'Jack of Diamonds']
```

What I think is happening is that it goes through the first time and appends the cards to jo's hand and bob's hand. It then goes through the second time and does the same thing. Why is it doing that, and how to I stop it so that it works correctly?
I have tried changing the indentation and the line of the `players.append(Player(name, hand))`, but that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing the cards to the top-level `hand` array and assigning it to each `Player` but never resetting it. Add `hand.clear()` after  `players.append(Player(name, hand))` or declare the `hand` variable in the `for` loop so as not to reuse it.